# Why calling addIncludePath from self has different results than from JModelLegacy

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-api

I'm trying to get an instance of a com_menus model from within my component. The following code works:

```
JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_menus/models/');
$model = self::getInstance('Item', 'MenusModel');
```

and gives me an instance of the menu item model which I can manipulate as I need, but this code

```
self::addIncludePath(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_menus/models/');
$model = self::getInstance('Item', 'MenusModel');
```

doesn't not give me a model, it just gives me `false`.

My component model extends `JModelList`. In my model, if I call `self::addIncludePath`, I get a different result than when I call  `JModelLegacy::addIncludePath`, even thought the static function `addIncludePath` is the same (`JModelList` is an alias for `ListModel`, which extends `BaseDatabaseModel` that defines the static function `addIncludePath` and `JModelLegacy` is an alias of `BaseDatabaseModel`).

The same static method is being executed, but clearly the context is making a difference in the result, but I don't understand why.

Why does calling the same static method in two different ways give two different results?

What is the correct/preferred way of instantiating a core component's model from with a component I'm developing? It seems odd to still be using JModelLegacy.